# One dropdown change is changing all other dropdown selected value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I’ve a requirement where I’ve multiple dropdownlist populated inside a for loop and doing a post back on dropdown change.
But the problem am facing now is, once one dropdown is changed, all the dropdown's selected value is set as the changed one.
Below is the code.

```
@foreach(var xxx in ViewBag.Items) 
{
@using (Html.BeginForm(“Action”, “Controller”))
{
    {
        List<SelectListItem> dropdownvalues = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var item in xxx.all_data.Split(','))
        {
            dropdownvalues.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = item,
                Text = item,
                Selected = (item == xxx.all_data.selectedvalue ? true : false)
            });
        }
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.element, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)(dropdownvalues), new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
    }
}
}
```

Please help.

Comment: How did you define ViewBag.Items?Could you share more code?

Answer (score 0):

With this loop you are creating multiple dom elements with the same id. Check for errors in your browser developer console.

Comment: i tried giving different id for each dropdown and the result is still the same